# "more" button expand only one specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with my jquery code. I have 2 section (contaier). Insdie this cointainers I have similar construction. Code below. What I want to do is when I click on "more" button in first container I want to show hidden info only in this div. When I click more in second container I want to show hidden info only in this div. How to do that? Now my button expand all hidden info in all divs

```js
$('.info').hide();
$('.show-info').click(function(){
  $('.info').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <p>adsadasdasd</p>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default show-info">more</a>
   <div class="info">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro perspiciatis sequi, modi architecto assumenda perferendis tenetur sunt optio quaerat est id atque, laudantium numquam distinctio sint provident, necessitatibus nobis nesciunt.</div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <p>adsadasdasd</p>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default show-info">more</a>
   <div class="info">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro perspiciatis sequi, modi architecto assumenda perferendis tenetur sunt optio quaerat est id atque, laudantium numquam distinctio sint provident, necessitatibus nobis nesciunt.</div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use `this` to ensure it expands only the related button.  Given your *current* html, this would likely be: `$(this).nextAll(".info").first().sldieToggle();`

Comment: Fixing the indent makes it more obvious and more robust: `$(this).closest(".row").find(".info").slideToggle()`

Comment: @freedomn-m What if I have this construction and I want to expand first div after my button?

<div class="row"></div>   <-- read more button in this row
<div class="info"></div>   <-- hidden info

<div class="row"></div>   <-- read more button in this row
<div class="info"></div>   <-- hidden info

Basically if button and hidden info are in two separates containers - https://codepen.io/eMeM/pen/Xapybz

Comment: Then use '.closest(".container")` assuming each row-pair is in it's own container (as per your question code).  You should be able to find it with a combination of `.closest()` and/or `.nextAll(".class").first()`.  The **key to the question** is that you need to use `this` as the question was about showing one, not all.

Comment: @freedomn-m
this works for me. Thank you!
$(this).closest('.row').nextAll().first().slideToggle("fast");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I click more in second container I want to show hidden info only in this div.
>
> Now my button expands all hidden info in all divs.

The issue is that you are using

```
$(".info").slideToggle()
```

which says: slideToggle *all* items with the class `.info` - instead, you need to limit to only the `.show-info` that matches the button clicked.

You do this by using `this` inside the event handler.

Given that information, finding the related item depends on the HTML structure and will be different for each scenario.  In the case for *this* question:

```
$('.info').closest(".row").hide();
$('.show-info').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.row').next().slideToggle("fast"‌​);
});
```

Where each info/show-info are on subsequent `.row` rows.

(The OPs comment of `.nextAll().first()` is the same as `.next()` - you would normally using `.nextAll(filter).first()`).

(You'll also need to change the initial `hide` so that it hides `.row` rows to match the slide).

---

**Update**: This assumes the following html as described in the question/comments:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <p>some info</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default show-info">more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="info">
       <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro perspiciatis sequi, modi architecto assumenda perferendis tenetur sunt optio quaerat est id atque, laudantium numquam distinctio sint provident, necessitatibus nobis nesciunt.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>second row of info</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default show-info">more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="info">
       <div>Second set of expanded info.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

which shows that if you're `toggling` `.row` then that's what you need to hide initially.

Note: rather than hide via js, it would be better to hide on load, ie:

```
<div class="row" style='display:none'>
    <div class="info">
```

Comment: What's the point to use $('.info').closest(".row").hide(); when my divs with hidden info have the same class. Is this wrong? And why if is? $('.info').hide();

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "when my divs with hidden info have the same class".  If you hide `.info` but then show `.row` then the row you show will still have a hidden info.

Answer (score 1):

Use `next()` function find the next info and toggle it. And also if you want to hide them when page load call hide on them onload or keep them in display none using css.

```js
$('.show-info').click(function(){
  $(this).next(".info").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<p>adsadasdasd</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default show-info">more</a>
<div class="info">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro perspiciatis sequi, modi architecto assumenda perferendis tenetur sunt optio quaerat est id atque, laudantium numquam distinctio sint provident, necessitatibus nobis nesciunt.</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<p>adsadasdasd</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default show-info">more</a>
<div class="info">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro perspiciatis sequi, modi architecto assumenda perferendis tenetur sunt optio quaerat est id atque, laudantium numquam distinctio sint provident, necessitatibus nobis nesciunt.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not how `.next()` works.  It returns the next item, then filters it to the class. So you either get one item or none, so no need for `.first()` and doesn't "find all the next infos" - replace with `.nextAll()` and what you've said/code is correct.

Comment: @freedomn-m Ahh missed it completely. Removed the first().

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to find the hidden info inside the current row and slideToggle it.

take a look at the snippet:

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <p>adsadasdasd</p>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-default show-info">more</a>
       <div class="info">
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro perspiciatis sequi, modi architecto assumenda perferendis tenetur sunt optio quaerat est id atque, laudantium numquam distinctio sint provident, necessitatibus nobis nesciunt.</div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <p>adsadasdasd</p>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-default show-info">more</a>
       <div class="info">
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro perspiciatis sequi, modi architecto assumenda perferendis tenetur sunt optio quaerat est id atque, laudantium numquam distinctio sint provident, necessitatibus nobis nesciunt.</div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script>
    $('.info').hide();
    $('.show-info').click(function(){
      
      $(this).parent().find('.info').slideToggle("fast");
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```js
$('.info').hide();
$('.show-info').click(function(){
  $('.info').slideUp('fast');
  $(this).closest(".row").find(".info").slideToggle('fast');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<p>adsadasdasd</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default show-info">more</a>
<div class="info">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro perspiciatis sequi, modi architecto assumenda perferendis tenetur sunt optio quaerat est id atque, laudantium numquam distinctio sint provident, necessitatibus nobis nesciunt.</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<p>adsadasdasd</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default show-info">more</a>
<div class="info">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro perspiciatis sequi, modi architecto assumenda perferendis tenetur sunt optio quaerat est id atque, laudantium numquam distinctio sint provident, necessitatibus nobis nesciunt.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what you did, not everyone seeking for an answer.

Comment: When you click on link then first hide all opened div and then find `.info` in current div..to open..